# is there any significance to modify Function Instance's prototype chain?

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

as [2ality](http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#the-details-of-subclassing) said in ECMAScript 6, 
subclassing looks as follows.

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    ···
}

class ColorPoint extends Point {
    constructor(x, y, color) {
        super(x, y);
        this.color = color;
    }
    ···
}

let cp = new ColorPoint(25, 8, 'green');
```

This code produces the following objects.

[image]

and I know classes in JavaScript are syntactical sugar over prototype-based inheritance. 
the typical implementation in plain old JavaScript just like follow,

```
function Parent(name) {
    this.name = name || 'parent'
}

function Child(name, age) {
    Parent.call(this, (name || 'child'))
    this.age = age || 0
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)
Child.prototype.constructor = Child

var c = new Child
```

but the prototype chains looks different than earlier, roughly like this

[image]

so my questions:

1. is there any way in ES5 to reassign `Function Instance`'s `[[Prototype]]` property that makes inheritance exactly equal to ES2015's (as you know `Object.setPrototypeOf()` was introduced to in ES2015)
2. is there any significance to modify Function Instance's(constructer) prototype chain?

Comment: 1) Kind of: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf#Polyfill 2) Are you asking what the purpose is? It's so that the child class inherits static methods from the parent class. But you could achieve the same effect by just copying over those properties.

Comment: @felix-kling thanks